# issue with fram hiding

Tags: java, hide, frame

I am having trouble hiding a new frame when I am trying to open a new one.  At the end of this code there is a call to start() method of another class and I would like this classes frame to be hidden but I cannot seem to access the from from its current location.

```
package InventoryApp;

//Import
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
 /**
 *
 * @author Curtis
 */
public class JSplash extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //declaration of variable objects
    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
    JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
    Color bgColor = new Color(0,0,255);
    Color firstColor = new Color(255,255,255);
    String first = "Welcome to DaemoDynamics!";
     String last = "Click the Button";
     String middle = "";
     String middle2 = "";


    int count = 1;  
    //Constructor
    public JSplash()
            {
                super("Item Inventory Application");
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setLayout (new BorderLayout());
                add(myButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                getContentPane().setBackground(bgColor);
                //adds action listener
                myButton.addActionListener(this);
            }
    //Paint method
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics e)
    {
        super.paint(e);
        e.setFont(myFont);
        e.setColor(firstColor);


          e.drawString(first, 14, 80);
          e.drawString(last, 70, 240);
          e.drawString(middle, 75, 150);
          e.drawString(middle2, 60, 175);
    }

     public static void begin()
     {
             final int TALL = 316;
             final int WIDE = 304;
             JSplash frame = new JSplash();
             frame.setSize(WIDE, TALL);
             frame.setVisible(true);
     }
    //Listener Method
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //First Time button hit
        if(count == 1)
        {
            middle = "Brighter Business";
                middle2 = "for A Brighter Future";
                last = "Click Again to Begin";
                repaint();
            //increases button count
            count ++;
        }
        else//if button count is not 1
        {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            FinalProject.start();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to compile.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: As an aside, your code suggest that you think this can be completed by throwing together random lines of code.  It can't.  You need to understand what is happening each line.

Answer (score 0):

The `frame` is declare as a local variable, and therefore is out of scope in the `actionPerformed()` method.